# RTS AI: where to start?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, real-time-strategy

I'd like to begin tinkering around with an RTS AI, but I'm having trouble finding a good environment to work with, ie a game that has been already created. I have looked at Spring RTS and Bos Wars, but they don't seem to be conducive to creating simple examples.

I am not totally opposed to writing my own game environment, it would just take a long time. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can get my feet wet without programming my own game?

Comment: Warzone 2100 is an open source RTS. Have a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warzone_2100

Answer (score 5):

There's actually a starcraft AI competition going on right now. The BWAPI ai api is very nice and should get you going very quickly. There are already many impressive entrants.

http://eis.ucsc.edu/StarCraftAICompetition

Edit :(, just realized how old this question is.

Answer (score 4):

I can not say anything about the other projects, but i can speak for Spring RTS:

It supports a plugin system for AI Interfaces, and as of January 2011, comes with a Native (C/C++) and a JVM (Java, Groovy, JRuby, ...) AI Interface plugin. A Python plugin is quite mayor already, but not yet considered stable. There are lots of C++ AIs to be used as reference, while for Java, there is a small tutorial and a few AIs.

As the base of all the interfaces is the same (the engine), they are very similar in nature, so it is also possible to use C++ AIs as a reference when writing a Java AI and vice versa.

The [AI development forum](http://springrts.com/phpbb/viewforum.php?f=15) and the #ai channel on the lobby (also reachable through IRC) may be of use too.

The engine has already been used for at least 7 AIs developed during university thesis.

The engine its self is mostly written in C++, uses the CMake build system and compiles on Linux+GCC and Windows+MinGW (unofficially also on MSVC). You may want to follow the guide under *Development - Compiling* on the projects homepage, which explains how to compile the engine, and in turn also gets you the source code of the engine and a few AIs.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ORTS](http://www.cs.ualberta.ca/~mburo/orts/), maintained by Michael Buro at the University of Alberta.

I haven't used it myself, but I've seen it in action since even before the first release in 2003, and it's definitely grown in leaps and bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Strarcraft II will come with a very complete, programmable, editor (some people even transformed it into a FPS). It will be released on July the 2nd.

Supreme Commander is also [moddable via Lua](http://supcom.wikia.com/wiki/Lua). There are several WWI - WWII strategy games also moddable via Lua.

On the Opensource front, [glest](http://glest.org) and [temulous](http://tremulous.net) have their source available; you might want to try modding them.

Finally, there's [0 A. D.](http://www.wildfiregames.com/0ad/), which is also opensource, but on alpha.

My recommendation, however, is that you give a look at [the Spring project](http://springrts.com/).

Comment: 0 A.D. is on alpha, and has a lot of dependencies for its graphics.

Comment: fixed the "beta <-> mismatch". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a few bucks, Garage Games has an RTS kit for its Torque game engine. http://www.garagegames.com/products/rts-genre-kit

This should allow you to begin writing some AI code immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but open source software is highly preferred.